# Should I ask a question about XYZ on a StackExchange site, or on XYZ home?

Tags: discussion, support, asking-questions

I often wonder whether a question should be asked on an Stack Exchange site or on the home site of the object of my question.

For example, I have asked a question about a library called Cucumber on Stack Overflow. My reasoning was that Stack Overflow was very active, easy to search, and thus offering good visibility for people with the same problem.

This question is probably a duplicate (I gave up search/FAQ after 10 min), but **does Stack Exchange has a general guideline on what questions we prefer on the sites?**

I remember in the early days, one great ambition of Stack Overflow was to be the reference on software-related questions. And I believe it succeeded and stays high. But some questions may be too granular for objective resolution on Stack Overflow, except perhaps by just linking to the right place on the web.

Anyway, a pointer to a bit I have missed, or a link to a duplicate thread, would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

Depends, if you have a question regarding "I'm trying to code XYZ, but I failed, here's why", your question is fit for Stack Overflow.

If, on the other hand, your question looks something like "Why is XYZ feature of ZYX this and not that?" or "When will the next stable version of ZYX be released?" Your question is off-topic and will be closed.

---

### As a golden rule

Ask yourself this

> Would I ask this question to a friend who knows ZYX? Will he be able to answer me? Or should I just ask the developer of ZYX because he's the only one who may be able to answer me?